# using file I/O in c#

Tags: c#

I have a project in c# for my object oriented programming class where I have to process an exam and its questions based on a .txt I provide, then spit out some information about the exam. https://gyazo.com/2f67407adf82fe4d071382bfdee5219e this is the txt file, the first line is the answers to each question and each following line holds the student number and their responses, the 0 signals the end of the .txt file(x represents no answer given). The program needs to calculate a student's final score with their student number next to it, the amount of students, the number of correct responses to each question, the min/max score and the average score attained by all students. Correct answer is +4 wrong answer is -1 and no answer is 0. The program needs to output this information to console like so. https://gyazo.com/0f1d80eeb6f44681bf6ab80f5934dcf8 (minus the max, min and avg score) and also print it to a .txt file as well. 
This is the code I have currently but am stumped on how to continue the program.

```
String line;
        string[] tokens;
        int id;
        try
        {
            //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\\exam.txt");

            //Read the first line of text
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            tokens = line.Split();
            id = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[0]);
            //Continue to read until you reach end of file
            while (id != 0)
            {
                //write the line to console window
                Console.WriteLine(tokens[1]);
                //Read the next line
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                tokens = line.Split();
                id = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[0]);
            }
            //close the file
            sr.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
        }
```

Comment: If you would like to prevent this question from being removed, you will need to provide specific details as to what you are looking for help with. What is your specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare each correct answer with each student answer. This should get you started:

```
//Read the first line of text
string line = sr.ReadLine();
// Correct answers
string [] answerKey = line.Split();
while (true)
{
    line = sr.ReadLine();
    tokens = line.Split();
    id = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[0]);
    if (id == 0) break;
    string [] studentAnswers = tokens[1].Split();
    int score = 0;
    // Compare correct answers to student answers
    for (int i = 0; i < answerKey.Length; i++) {
        if (answerKey[i] == studentAnswers[i]) {
            score += 4;
        }
        else if (studentAnswers[i] != "X") {
            score -= 1;
        }
    }
    // Do something with score here.....
}
//close the file
sr.Close();
Console.ReadLine();
```